# What is a loadbalancer in Kubernetes, Why do different Kubernetes engines like GKE have their own loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, aws-application-load-balancer

`Loadbalancer` is used to handle a request and forward that request to a particular pod, but my question is how does the **GKE** LoadBalancer work, how is it different from the LoadBalancer we have in **minikube**, and how should we use LoadBalancer properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **GKE** when you add a Service of type LoadBalancer, it makes the necessary Google Cloud API calls to create either an external network LB, or an internal TCP/UDP LB.

The `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` annotation denotes an internal LB; otherwise, GKE creates an external network load balancer.   This type of LB operates at layer 3/4, and is not an application load balancer, and thus not aware of HTTP requests or headers.

The LB service was designed for deployments in external cloud providers. In **Minikube** you need to use the `tunnel` feature to expose it.  `tunnel` runs as a process, creating a network route on the host to the service CIDR of the cluster using the cluster’s IP address as a gateway. The `tunnel` command exposes the external IP directly to programs running on the host OS.